# Common way to find apache directory and logs

Tags: bash, apache, shell, filepath

is there a common way to find the apaches directory and its log files?
I found that question so often in the web but never a satisfying answer for it.

I would like to write a bash script that can find the path and the log files on any server.
But I struggle now with versions. Sometimes there is httpd installed and sometimes apache2. So that is the first impediment.
Then I found out that often the /etc/apache2/envvars were not initialized and so there is no access to APACHE_LOG_DIR and so on.

Isn't there really no easy to way to find the installation path and from there log files???

Comment: There is so many different ways to install and configure apache. If there is no logdir and log defined, you wouldn't find anything. If you want write a _generic_ script, it should be an optional config of it. If you want a script for a defined park, you could analyze all usages and write a specific script to match all your cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running `apachectl -t -d DUMP_RUN_CFG` on versions that support it and parsing that output to both find log files and where the config files can be found.

If `DUMP_RUN_CFG` isn't supported, you could still use `apachectl -V` and look at the `HTTPD_ROOT` value to get the root of the config directories, and other values like `SERVER_CONFIG_FILE` to get the name of the config file and so forth.